# Problems deleting a specific row in android studio (execSQL)

Tags: sqlite

this is my first question in this forum. I´ve a problem with my first app. When I try to delete a register, I always delete the one I want and also the last register, and I can´t imaging why. Any possible explanation? Thanks a lot. This is my code (I´ve used a lot of different codes, but always happens de same. Two deleted register!)

```
public boolean delete_register(int tmp_a_id){
    boolean result=false;
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getReadableDatabase();
    db.execSQL("DELETE FROM tableXX WHERE a_id=" + tmp_a_id);
    db.close();
    return result;
}
```

Comment: Shouldn't that be `getWritableDatabase()` since you're modifying it? (Also, even though `tmp_a_id` is an integer and thus this isn't a case where you're opening yourself up to SQL injection by including it directly in the query, it's a good habit to use a parameter and bind the value to that anyways.)

Comment: Thanks for answering. I´ve already try with getWritableDatabase, with no diferent result. And yes, It´s better not to include the parameter directly, just did it as last resource, but again, with no diferent result.

Comment: Error detected. Error caused by a dbhandler not closed.